# Angularjs $http.post, asp.net mvc controller gets null

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

In my Angularjs service I have this code:

```
$http.post("/EditWorkout/GetId", data).error(function (responseData) {
            console.log("Error !" + responseData);
        });
```

And I have this method in my ASP.net controller:

```
       [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetId(string routineId)
        {
            try
            {
                string x = routineId;
                return Json(new {success = true});
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Json(new { success = false, errorMessage = ex.Message });
            }

        }
```

I've put a break point on `return Json(new {success = true});` and it gets fired, but my routineId is for some reason null, and data which I send using angular's $http.post isn't.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: What's inside the `data` variable? And what's the `Content-Type` request header being sent? Look at the development console of your Google Chrome browser to see the exact request being made.

Comment: Yes, it is a variable, I've even tried using "sometext" instead of data, and Content-Type is application/json;charset=utf-8

Comment: And Status Code is  HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
$http.post("/EditWorkout/GetId", { routineId : data}).error(function (responseData) {
            console.log("Error !" + responseData);
        });
```

Comment: and... why does this work? is it just because routineId is the same name in the controller and json object?

Comment: @chiliYago that is correct. Your JSON will be parsed as the C# object that is a parameter(s) on your API controller so they must match or will get an error.